# a new sql inside a sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have a sql where I get rows from my mysql where nummer = nummer, but I want to get some info from another table as well.

```
 <?php
    $Id = $_GET['Id'];
    $nummer = $_GET['nummer'];
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);      
    $sql = 'SELECT Id, nummer ,start, job_art, work_id, slut FROM rum WHERE nummer = :nummer and slut = ""'; 
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->bindValue(':nummer', $Id);
    $q->execute();  
    $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);     

    ?>  

<?php while ($r = $q->fetch()): ?>
<tr>
<td class="line"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['start'])?></td>
 <td class="line"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['job_art'])?></td>
```

here I want to get the work_id from my tabel workers and post it as the row hvem

```
<td class="line"><?php  if ($r["slut"] ==  "")
{
    echo '<a href="afslut_opgave.php?work_id='.$r["work_id"]. '&Id=' .$r["Id"]. '&nummer=' .$r["nummer"].'" class=bluelink> Afslut</a>';

    }
    else
    {
    echo $row["slut"];
    }
?></td>

    </tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

I tryed to put a new sql, but my endwhile stops the rest of the info, and I cant see my work_id 
how can I solve that problem?

my table rum looks like this

Id ---- nummer----work_id------job_art  (in the table I only have the work_id (could be pa for painter)

My table workers looks like this

Id -----work_id------hvem (I want the row hvem to apear) work_id = pa is hvem = painter

```
 <?php
    $Id = $_GET['Id'];
    $nummer = $_GET['nummer'];
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);      
    $sql = 'SELECT Id, nummer ,start, job_art, work_id, slut FROM rum WHERE nummer = :nummer and slut = ""'; 
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->bindValue(':nummer', $Id);
    $q->execute();  
    $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);     

    ?>  

 <?php while ($r = $q->fetch()): ?>
<tr>
<td class="line"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['start'])?></td>
  <td class="line"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['job_art'])?></td>
    <?php 
        $work_d = $_GET['work_id'];     
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);      
     $sql = 'SELECT * from rum FULL OUTER JOIN workers on work_id = work_id'; 
     $q = $pdo->query($sql);
     $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);?>

  <td class="line"> <?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['hvem'])?>
  </td>
  <td height="25">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
 <?php endwhile; ?>
```

here I get a error Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message

This worked :)

```
$sql = 'SELECT hvem from workers INNER JOIN rum on workers.work_id = rum.work_id WHERE nummer = :nummer';
```

Comment: I would probably use a join or a subselect. It would be a great idea to show us the tables involved with some sample data and the desired result.

Comment: First: MySQL doesn't support `FULL OUTER JOIN`. Second: use either a left join and deal with a NULL value or an INNER JOIN if there's a corresponding row in workers for certain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use a join, for example for the following given tables:

```
id  name       id    name
--  ----       --    ----
1   Pirate     2     Pirate
2   Monkey     null  null
3   Ninja      4     Ninja
4   Spaghetti  null  null
```

You can join the table the following way:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB
ON TableA.name = TableB.name
```

> Left outer join produces a complete set of records from Table A, with
>   the matching records (where available) in Table B. If there is no
>   match, the right side will contain null.

You can read more about joins [on this blog](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) or check the [official documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).

Comment: Idont know but maybe its because you said you are not sure if your example will work?

Comment: Maybe, could be the link, someone could have thought i was link dumping :/